# How to get observation frequency counts from multiple dataset into one table?

Tags: sql, count, sas, dataset, frequency

I have a bunch of large datasets.

DS_1 (contains all unique IDs and names):

```
ID   Name
1    Apple
2    Banana
3    Cherry
```

DS_2:

```
ID   Observation
1    Apple detail
1    Apple detail
1    Apple detail
2    Banana detail
2    Banana detail
3    Cherry detail
3    Cherry detail
3    Cherry detail
```

DS_3:

```
ID   Observation
2    Banana detail
2    Banana detail
3    Cherry detail
```

I'm looking to create a new dataset that shows frequency counts across the datasets (and lastly calculates Total_Obs). I would output something like this:

```
ID   Name      DS_2    DS_3   Total_Obs
1    Apple     3       0      3
2    Banana    2       2      4
3    Cherry    3       1      4
```

The datasets are fairly large.  Is there a more efficient way to do this apart from concatenating the datasets and doing a frequency table? Or having to creating a bunch of sorted frequency tables, then merging by ID across all the datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below -

```
Select t1.id As id
      ,t1.name As name
      ,coalesce(DS_2_obs,0) as DS_2_obs
      ,coalesce(DS_3_obs,0) as DS_3_obs
      ,coalesce(DS_2_obs,0) + coalesce(DS_3_obs,0) As Total_Obs
from DS_1 t1
left join (Select id, count(1) as DS_2_obs from DS_2 group by id) t2
on t1.id = t2.id
left join (Select id, count(1) as DS_3_obs from DS_3 group by id) t3
on t1.id = t3.id;
```

Also, you should always tag which Database you are using.

If the above SQL takes a lot of time, instead of t2 and t3 as inline queries you can consider creating aggregate observation tables with frequency/counts and having an index on id. That way when you join the observation aggregates with the primary table, the join can be faster based on indexes.

Comment: @Asian_ricecakes, it it works perfectly for you then you should accept the answer. I don't know if you know , you can appreciate the effort others put to help you by accepting the answer.

Comment: Great to know that it worked out. Would be great if you can accept the answer (if it worked). Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view to stack the source data sets.  The view will not consume a large amount of disk space.  The stack can used by a variety of procedures or steps to either produce an output report or an actual count summary transposition.

Example:

```
* generate some sample data, a master table and 30 detail tables;

data master;
  do id = 1 to 200;  * ids 1 to 200;
    length name $36;
    name = repeat (cats(id,'_'),5);
    output;
  end;
run;

data _null_;

  call streaminit(123);

  retain id 0;

  declare hash h(multidata:'yes');
  h.defineKey('id');
  h.defineData('id');
  h.defineDone();

  do index = 1 to 30;
    do i = 1 to rand('integer', 100);  * upto 100 ids;

      id = rand('integer', 200);  * random id;
      do j = 1 to rand('integer', 20); * replicated upto 20 times;
        h.add();
      end;
    end;

    h.output (dataset:cats('child_',index));
    h.clear();

  end;
run;
```

Stacking view

```
data assemble_v / view=assemble_v;
  if (_n_ = 1) then do;
    declare hash names(dataset:'master');
    length id 8 name $36;
    names.defineKey('id');
    names.defineData('name');
    names.defineDone();
  end;

  set child_1-child_30 indsname=_source;

  source = _source;
  if names.find() ne 0 then name = '*missing*';

  retain unity 1;
run;
```

Output presentation of counts

```
options missing = '0';
proc tabulate data=assemble_v out=partitions(index=(order=(id name)));
  title "TABULATE: ID Counts for detail tables";
  class id name;
  class source / order=data;
  table id*name, n=''*(source=' ' all='Total') / nocellmerge;
run;

options missing = '0';

proc report data=assemble_v;
  title "REPORT: ID Counts for detail tables";
  columns id name source,unity ('Total' unity=Total);
  define id / group ;
  define name / group;
  define source / ' ' across order=data;
  define unity / ' ' ;
  define total / ' ' ;
run;
```

[image]
[image]

Data transformation of counts

```
proc freq data=assemble_v noprint ;
  table id*name*source / out=combos(keep=id name source count);
run;

proc transpose data=combos out=wide(drop=_name_ _label_);
  by id name;
  var count;
  id source;
run;
```

[image]